# jQuery Ajax call doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a page with jQuery Ajax and then display just a simple response if it worked or not, but it doesn't seem to get anything done. In FireBug I don't even get an error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$('.doit').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.domain.com/page.php?do=it",
    type: "GET"
    success: function (data) {
        $(".result").html('<strong>Done!</strong>');
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $(".result").html('<strong>Houston, we have a problem.</strong>');
    },
    timeout: 15000
  });
});
</script>

<a href="" class="doit">Do it</a>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: There is a missing comma "," after `type: "GET"`

Comment: And wrap your JS inside `$(document).ready(function(){ your code here });`, so that `.doit` is defined. Otherwise it may not work.

Comment: That was it, thanks guys! :) If you post an official answer I will accept it!

Comment: Done. Just had to wait a few minutes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the comma after `type: "GET"`. Also, as mentioned by @blex in a comment, you should put your bindings inside an ondomready context, to make sure that your element has been loaded before binding.

```
 $(function(){
    $('.doit').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.domain.com/page.php?do=it",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".result").html('<strong>Done!</strong>');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $(".result").html('<strong>Houston, we have a problem.</strong>');
        },
        timeout: 15000
      });
    });
 });
```